# C# (WPF) methods calling from different classses

Tags: c#, wpf, oop, methods

I'm very new to coding. I have a problem when calling method from B to class A, when input variable involved. Please explain why a.PrintAfromB(); giving me 0 value. How to overcome the situation.?
I see some examples use MVVM. But those are very complex for me in this stage. Seems like i'm getting the input variable incorrectly or calling methods incorrectly. I'm sucked and cannot move forward without resolving this.

> Main

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window {
    public MainWindow(){
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

        B b = new B();
        A a = new A();

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        b.Bat = double.Parse(one.Text);
        b.PrintB();
        a.PrintAfromB();
        a.PrintAfromBB();
    }
}
```

> A

```
class A
{
    double Apple { get; set; }    
    B b1 = new B();           
    public void PrintAfromB() {

        Console.WriteLine("Calling method from B where input involved: "+b1.CallB());
    }

    public void PrintAfromBB() {

        Console.WriteLine("Calling method from B where input not involved: " + b1.CallBB());
    }
}
```

> B

```
public class B{
   public double Bat { get; set; }
   public double k = 0;

    public void PrintB(){
        k = Bat;
        Console.WriteLine("test input value" +k);
    }

    public double CallB(){
        return 10 * Bat;
    }

    public double CallBB(){
        return 10 * 10;
    }
}
```

> XAML

```
<Window x:Class="inputtest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:inputtest"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="62,141,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="one" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="198,134,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="10" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
    <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="380,263,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click"/>

</Grid>
```

Comment: your screen name gives away what I said when first looking at your code `YIKES`, I would suggest you use more meaningful names when creating variables, I would read / google for a free online `C# Basics Tutorial` and understand / focus on the `Class Section` I would also learn how to use the debugger, set breakpoints and start stepping thru this code. start with classic winforms WPF is a bit advanced for a beginner

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestions, will follow that. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is A Class has another instance of B different from one in the Main.

To make A print something you entered, you should put B instance into A.

so make A like below:

```
class A
{
  B b1;
  public A(B b){
    b1 = b;
  }

  double Apple { get; set; }    

  public void PrintAfromB() {
    Console.WriteLine("Calling method from B where input involved: "+ b1.CallB());
  }

  public void PrintAfromBB() {
    Console.WriteLine("Calling method from B where input not involved: " + b1.CallBB());
  }
}
```

and then change Main like below:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window {
  public MainWindow(){
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = this;
  }

  B b = new B();
  A a = new A(b);

  private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
      b.Bat = double.Parse(one.Text);
      b.PrintB();
      a.PrintAfromB();
      a.PrintAfromBB();
  }
}
```

hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried changing code as you suggested. 
But in the main class when I entered a parameter "b". its giving me error.
**a field initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field method or property creating objects**

Comment: I tried moving creating object inside button and error went away. I don't know its an appropriate to do so. BTW, not its working. Thanks